# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable for list passed in as parameter to a function

Tags: python

Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order.

I keep getting the error, and I don't understand why.

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
    if (nums[i] not in current):
```

This is my code:

```
def permute(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        output = []
        self.backtracking(nums, output, [],0, len(nums))
        return output 
        
    
    def backtracking(self, nums, outputList, current, length, maxLength):
        if (length == maxLength):
            outputList.append(current)
        
        for i in nums:
            if (nums[i] not in current):
                self.backtracking(nums, outputList, current.append(nums[i]), length+1, maxLength)
```

Comment: How are you populating `nums`? One of the elements is `None` and not an integer.

Comment: I'm pretty nums is all integers. This error is generated by the test case when nums = [1,2,3]

Comment: add `print(nums)` before the conditional that is erroring to verify it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: also, you probably wanted `if i not in current` instead